# "Trick" installer into installing when I haven't restarted

Tags: windows, vmware

OS: Windows 7 Professional (64-bit)
App: VMWare Workstation

Need to install VMWare workstation today without restarting my computer - but the installer won't proceed until the computer has been restarted.

Is there a way to "trick" the installer into thinking I've restarted my computer?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is, but you have to be absolutely sure you want to do it. 
VMWare installs drivers (for network and USB support) and those only get reloaded upon system start. So while you can "trick" the installer, you'd get a partial and unstable behavior of your system at best.

To achieve what you want without too many registry browsing, get a startup listing tool (like [Sysinternals AutoRuns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902)). Look under the RunOnce tab/column, locate the VMWare's installer's execution, copy the line, click Windows Key + R, paste the line and hit enter.

This should run the portion of the installer that was originally cheduled to run after the next restart.

My suggestion: reboot your machine: fater, cleaner, safer.